# How do I conditionally change the aspect ratio of charts in R's Shiny package?

Tags: r, shiny

Just playing with [Shiny](http://rstudio.github.com/shiny/tutorial/) and loving it already. But how do I get charts in the reactivePlot / plotOutput combination to be of different sizes depending on which chart is plotted?

In this first example, I have selected the "Yield curve" analysis and get the aspect ratio I want:

[image]

But when I choose another analysis, in this case a heatmap, it is now the same size as the "Yield Curve" chart which distorts it (cells should be square, not rectangular).

[image]

How can I change the chart size depending on which chart has been selected? I've tried putting the height parameter = NA, NULL or "" but it doesn't like any of those.

Separately, but in the same application, how can I get some whitespace between the top selectInput and the textInputs in the sidebarPanel? I have tried h4("  ") but doesn't work.

Here is my ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel(h1("SAGB Relative Value Tool")),
    sidebarPanel(
        h4("Choose analysis:"),
        selectInput("analysis1", "", 
            choices = c("Yield curve", "Optical asset swap spreads", 
                        "Cheap dear box", "Cheap dear charts", "Switch signaliser", 
                        "Barbells")),
        h4(" "),
        h4("Yield override:"),
        lapply(bondNames, function(x)
            textInput(paste(x, "bond"), x, last(sagb$sagb)[x]))
    ),
    mainPanel(
        h3(textOutput("AnalysisHeader")),
        plotOutput("AnalysisOutput", height = "10in"))
))
```

and here is my server.r

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$AnalysisHeader  <- reactiveText(function() {
        input$analysis1
    })


    output$AnalysisOutput <- reactivePlot(function() {
        switch(input$analysis1,
            "Yield curve" = wo(whichOut = 1),
            "Optical asset swap spreads" = wo(whichOut = 2),
            "Cheap dear box" = wo(whichOut = 3),
            "Cheap dear charts" = wo(whichOut = 4),
            "Switch signaliser" = wo(whichOut = 5),
            "Barbells" = wo(whichOut = 6)
        )

    })


})
```

Comment: bondNames is a global list variable in the program which calls runApp(), and which contains the names of the 12 active bonds in the south african government bond ("SAGB") market. Here it is used for the to create the sidebar yield override inputs (somewhat sloppily though - I have only just now discovered numericInput, and I should use a for loop not an lapply, and my paste omits a sep = "" argument). Anyway not relevant to the question. wo() and sagb$sagb data structures are also part of the containing code, for example.

Comment: I second the question (in case people from Rstudio want to know how many persons are interested in this feature!), [my plot is currently unreadable](http://i.stack.imgur.com/liY3O.png), but I can't statically set the height as the number of plots varies according to dynamic UIs ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(sometimes it's a good idea to [RTFM](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shiny/shiny.pdf) (talking to my self as well, cf my comment to OP)

```
reactivePlot(func, width = "auto", height = "auto", ...)

width    The width of the rendered plot, in pixels; or ’auto’ to use the offsetWidth of
         the HTML element that is bound to this plot. You can also pass in a function
         that returns the width in pixels or ’auto’; in the body of the function you may
         reference reactive values and functions.
*height* The height of the rendered plot, in pixels; or ’auto’ to use the offsetHeight
         of the HTML element that is bound to this plot. You can also pass in a function
         that returns the width in pixels or ’auto’; in the body of the function you may
         reference reactive values and functions.
...      Arguments to be passed through to png. These can be used to set the width,
         height, background color, etc.
```

however, so far I couldn't manage to make to work (with `height="15in"`)...

```
Error in switch(units, `in` = res, cm = res/2.54, mm = res/25.4, px = 1) *  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

**EDIT**: it's now working, `height` has to be numeric, with optional `units="px"` and `res` certainly something to convert `units` to pixels.

**EDIT 2**: and don't forget to update Shiny [to the last version], it fixes some bugs I faced.

**EDIT 3**: here is an example where the height is dynamically changed:

```
getVarHeight <- function() {
    return(getNumberOfPlots() * 400)
}
output$out <- reactivePlot(doPlots, height=getVarHeight)
```

You can relate the snippet to this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liY3O.png), where `getNumberOfPlots` returns the number of graph to plot.

**EDIT 4**: if you want to display *several* images, you should change the `height` in 'ui.R' as well: this value is directly transmitted to CSS, and the default value is `400px`. So if your images are bigger, they will overlap and only the to 400px will be visible ...

```
plotOutput(outputId = "plot_rain", height="100%"))
```

Comment: thanks Kevin - I did actually RTFM and saw this ;) but what do I put in in the plotOutput function, which has a default height of 400px.

Comment: I believe you can also pass `height="auto"` to the `plotOutput` function, that should make the plotOutput use the "natural" height of its contents. (Be sure NOT to use `height="auto"` for both `reactivePlot` and `plotOutput` at the same time though: each will be depending on the other to determine the height and my guess is you'll end up with 0px height.)