# png() iteration error in R

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, png

Currently I am having issue with the png() function inside of a for loop. Below is a simplified example of code. The vector represents indicator values for multiple shape file I am trying to iterate through, plot, and save in a png.

```
match <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
for(m in 1:length(match)){
  png("WMA", m, "/_example_plot.png")
  p <- c(plot(match[m]))
  dev.off()
}
```

I am receiving the below error from my script:

> Error in switch(units, `in` = res, cm = res/2.54, mm = res/25.4, px =
>   1) * : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Traceback below

> 2..geometry(width, height, units, res)
>
> 1.png("WMA", m, "/_example_plot.png")

The plotting code and file path work fine on their own. I have tested all my png() functions using some of the indicator values in the match vector. However, when I iterate through each indicator value I receive the error.

This [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792195/how-do-i-conditionally-change-the-aspect-ratio-of-charts-in-rs-shiny-package) post leads me to believe I should create a function to set the geometry of png(). However, I'm not sure how to do this/ why I would need to. Any and all information is appreciated as always :)

Comment: Should it not be: `png(paste0("WMA/", m, "_example_plot.png"))`? So all pngs are stored in map WMA as 1_example_plot.png, 2_example_plot.png, etc.

Comment: Also check out `ggsave`

Comment: @Florian Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem is that you want to create a changing name of PNG. The error is that you do not concatenate the name by using `paste0` function. That is:`png(paste0("WMA", m, "/_example_plot.png"))`.
In your code the PNG function had a first argument `"WMA"`, a second argument `m` and a third argument  `"/_example_plot.png")`.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly